# how to load dataset on top of existing dataset in MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, database

- I have 2 MYSQL server A and B, and both have a table of the same name
  and same DB schema.
- Server A has 3000 rows while server B has 10000+rows.
- In regarding these rows, they do not have any overlap. Both are unique dataset.

And I have already execute "mysqldump ... " to have Server A's data dumped in a file, so what is the easy way for me to load Server A's data on this table into Server B, on top of the existing Server B dataset ? Is there a command way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

When making the dump, use the `--no-create-info` option. This leaves out the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements in the dump file that would remove the existing table.

The dump file will then just contain the `INSERT` statements, which will append to the existing table.

If you can't recreate the dump file, open it in an editor and delete those statements.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. first time I am doing that. thanks.